# How to pick proper number of threads, workers, processes for Dask when running in an ephemeral environment as single machine and cluster

Tags: dask, dask-distributed, aws-fargate, dask-kubernetes

Our company is currently leveraging [prefect.io](https://prefect.io) for data workflows (ELT, report generation, ML, etc). We have just started adding the ability to do parallel task execution, which is powered by [Dask](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/index.html).  Our flows are executed using ephemeral [AWS Fargate](https://aws.amazon.com/fargate/) containers, which will use Dask LocalCluster with a certain number of workers, threads, processes passed into the LocalCluster object.

Our journey on Dask will look very much like this:

1. Continue using single machine LocalCluster until we out grow max cpu/memory allowed
2. When we out grow a single container, spawn additional worker containers on the initial container (a la [dask-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/)) and join them to the LocalCluster.

We're currently starting with containers that have 256 cpu(.25 vCPU) and 512 memory and pinning the LocalCluster to 1 n_workers and 3 threads_per_worker to get a reasonable amount of parallelism.  However, this really is guess work.  1 n_workers since its a machine with less than 1 vcpu and 3 threads because that doesn't sound crazy to me based on my previous experience running other python based applications in Fargate.  This seems to work fine in a very simply example that just maps a function against a list of items.

```
RENEWAL_TABLES = [
'Activity',
'CurrentPolicyTermStaus',
'PolicyRenewalStatus',
'PolicyTerm',
'PolicyTermStatus',
'EndorsementPolicyTerm',
'PolicyLifeState'
]

RENEWAL_TABLES_PAIRS = [
    (i, 1433 + idx) for idx, i in enumerate(RENEWAL_TABLES)
]


@task(state_handlers=[HANDLER])
def dummy_step():
    LOGGER.info('Dummy Step...')
    sleep(15)


@task(state_handlers=[HANDLER])
def test_map(table):
    LOGGER.info('table: {}...'.format(table))
    sleep(15)


with Flow(Path(__file__).stem, SCHEDULE, state_handlers=[HANDLER]) as flow:
    first_step = dummy_step()
    test_map.map(RENEWAL_TABLES_PAIRS).set_dependencies(upstream_tasks=[first_step])
```

I see no more than 3 tasks executed at once.

I would really like to understand how to best configure n_workers(single machinne), threads, processes as we expand the size of the single machine out to adding remote workers.  I know it depends on my workload, but you could see a combination of things in a single flow where one task does an extract from a database to a csv and another task run a pandas computation.  I have seen things online where it seems like it should be threads = number of cpus requested for the documentation, but it seems like you can still achieve parallelism with less than one cpu in Fargate.

Any feedback would be appreciated and could help others looking to leverage Dask in a more ephemeral nature.

Given that Fargate increments from .25 -> .50 -> 1 -> 2 -> 4 for vCPU, I think it’s safe to go with a 1 worker to 1 vcpu setup. However, would be helpful to understand how to choose a good upper limit for number of threads per worker given how Fargate vcpu allotment works.

Comment: Hi @braunk !  Thanks for asking a question.  Unfortunately this question is probably too broad to answer here.  Stack overflow is really great for specific questions like "what does this keyword mean?" but less good for "here is my situation, what should I do" sorts of questions.  Unfortunately I'm not sure that there is a great resource for you today.  I encourage you to try to break up your situation into smaller questions that are more likely to be useful for others as well.

Comment: Based on research on threading versus processes since I submitted this, I feel we have a good idea of how to move forward.  Thank you for the feedback and I will make sure to make the next question more specific.  Thanks to you and all the Dask contributors for creating such a great teamwork.  Keep up the great work.